# Send silent push notification from Firebase console

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

Trying to prove a concept I've been working on for a while, which involves my app recieving a silent notification. I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging as it has less overhead than native APNs for the developer.

I know FCM supports silent notifications when you build the payload yourself on your own backend, which is of course my intention. However, I want to make sure I can do what I want to do with this notification, and therefore want to prove it using the FCM console before I spend time writing my backend.

I have managed to send standard notifications from here, but not silent ones. Even when I include the `content-available` flag I'm still alerted. I think this is due to FCM always including the `alert` parameter in the JSON. Is there a way to disable this in the test console?

Many Thanks,

Comment: FCM does not support silent push notification as of now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to send notifications different from the standard kind from the Firebase Console.

A quite convenient way is to use [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) or curl with a set Authorization Header.

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization:key=<YOUR-API-KEY>"  -X POST -d '{ "data": { "foo": "1","bar": "2"},"to" : "<YOUR-DEVICE-TOKEN>"}' https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

Comment: You actually CAN send silent notifications using "content_available" set to true.

Comment: i was making this same mistake since long time . and i was not aware of it . even i have contacted FCM support but even they also could not tell me properly that how to send silent notification through their message console . thanks for making this clear . i am using remote notification functionality first time and i implemented FCM . now how to check whether my app could get silent notifications in background ? how to send silent notification ? through which method ? please guide me through this .

Answer (score 8):

You actually CAN send silent notifications from FCN. Check [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options).

> Note: On iOS, set content_available when the app server needs to send a send-to-sync message. An inactive client app executes your logic in the background, while an app in the foreground passes the message to didReceiveRemoteNotification:.

Notice that the key you have to use is `content_available`, with underscore; different from `content-available` which is with a hyphen.

Comment: Yes, but it still requires an external REST client. The question was regarding doing so with the FCM web console.

Comment: The link https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options doesn't contain neither `silent`, nor `content_available`.

Comment: Thats saved me days, thank you. I spent few hours split in to couple of days face‍♂️