# Can I send a silent push notification from a Firebase cloud function?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to send a silent APNs (iOS) remote notification from a [Firebase Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)? If so, how can this be done? I want to send data to iOS app instances when the app is not in the foreground, without the user seeing a notification.

I currently send a notification that can be seen by users:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotifications = functions.database.ref('/events/{pushId}').onWrite(event => {
  const id = event.params.pushId

  const payload = {
    notification: {
      title: 'An event has occurred!',
      body: 'Please respond to this event.',
      event_id: id
    }
  };

  return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("events", payload);
});
```

I would like to be able to send that `id` to the app without a visual notification.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured out how to modify my code to successfully send a silent notification. My problem was that I kept trying to put `content_available` in the `payload`, when it really should be in `options`. This is my new code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotifications = functions.database.ref('/events/{pushId}').onWrite(event => {
  const id = event.params.pushId

  const payload = {
    data: {
      title: 'An event has occurred!',
      body: 'Please respond to this event.',
      event_id: id
    }
  };

  const options = {
    content_available: true
  }

  return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("events", payload, options);
});
```

I successfully received the silent notification on my iOS device after implementing `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler` and `userNotificationCenter:willPresent:withCompletionHandler`.

Comment: hi , i have the same problem . do you know how to send that content_available: true , through FCM message console ? i am sending content_available: true through FCM message console but i am getting normal notification only , not the silent notification . what should i do ? like you said , we have to send in options , then how could i send like that ?

Comment: Hi @Moxarth, I don't think it is possible to send a silent notification through the console. The console is pretty limited and doesn't seem to support non-standard notifications. (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43119052/send-silent-push-notification-from-firebase-console) I'm not sure there's a good reason to send them through the console anyway.

Comment: i wants to check for the test, whether i am getting silent notification or not . so i was sending it through the FCM message console . so according to you , what should i use or any method to send silent notification to my app ? suggestions ? please guide me through this . i am using notification functionality first time . so . thanks for pointing me to that direction .

Comment: You could create a cloud function similar to the one I posted above. I used a database trigger, but you could modify it to use an HTTP trigger instead. Then to run the function you would go to the function's URL in your browser. You could also modify the function to send to a specific device instead of a topic.

Comment: okay , i ll look into that and i ll try to implement that way . thanks . i was not looking towards that direction . thanks for pointing me towards that .

Answer (score -5):

If you're talking about APNs notifications, the answer is: No, you can't send a notification without visualisation. You can only disable a sound. But, you can passed an FCM Data message without visualisation. You can read about it here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

```
 {  
   "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
   "data" : {
     "Nick" : "Mario",
     "body" : "great match!",
     "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
   }
}
```

Comment: In that case, I would be interested in understanding how I can send a FCM data message from a Firebase cloud function. I have tried many formats for the payload, without success. How would the code I posted in my original question look like if it was modified to send an FCM data message?

Comment: For the record it is in fact possible to "send a notification without visualization". In iOS this is called a "silent notification".