# Paylod for ios silent push notification to update tab bar item badge using Firebase Cloud Function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I have all push notifications working fine.

But what is missing is the ability to handle silent push notifications when the app is in the background without the need for the user to tap on the notification when it appears to process the notification.

The following is the payload code from my deployed Firebase Cloud Function written in JavaScript but it doesn't work. The notification is displayed when app is in background but no delegate methods are called for the tab bar item badge to be updated.

I understand that in order to enable this I need to add the `content-available` flag to my payload.

I have enabled Background Fetch and Remote Notifications to my app and declared `userNotificationCenter willPresent` and `userNotificationCenter didReceive` delegate method.

```
const payload = {
            notification: {
              title: "I'm " + senderName,
              body: notificationBody,
              'content-available' : 1
            },
            data: {
              SENDER_NAME: senderName,
              SENDER_ID: fromId,
              NOTIFICATION: 'invite'

            }//end data
        }//end payload
```

Comment: First of all you are not sending a **silent** push notification at all, because you need to set `content-available : true` as a payload property. And you have to use **true** and not *1* because you are sending an FCM payload and not a APN payload. Moreover you need to remove the notification node. If it's silent, you don't wanna show any notification ain't it? Then you need to override the delegate method `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`

Comment: Read carefully the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html). That said, pay attation at the difference between a "background" app and a "swipe-closed" app. In the latter case you won't be able to receive the silent notification.

Comment: thanks @shadowsheep for your feedback. I did manage to solve my problem with a solution found here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46058774/can-i-send-a-silent-push-notification-from-a-firebase-cloud-function] as this is an FCM function the the `content_available` should be specified in the `options` instead of the `payload`

Comment: So I guess that the json object you have posted in your question is totally misleading because it's wrong and if you create the payload with the FCM function API and its model structures that brings to a totally different one for sure (under the roots). If you use it with postman for example, with fcm Rest API,  it will never works. Anyway, if you did your work done, I suggest you to remove your question that you need no more. Or respond itself to it providing the exact working code you have written to make it work.

Comment: if you refer to my question again in particular the line _The following is the payload code from my deployed Firebase Cloud Function written in JavaScript but it doesn't work._ it is clear in saying that the code pasted was part of a FCF Javascript function and thus not misleading.

Comment: ^^, okay. And now, that you have a working example. What's the correct JSON payload you got?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my question with the help of the question link as per the comments above. As this is an FCM function the the `content_available` should be specified in the `options` instead of the `payload`

```
            const payload = {
                notification: {
                  title: senderName + " sent you a message",
                  body: notificationBody
                },
                data: {
                  SENDER_NAME: senderName,
                  SENDER_ID: fromId,
                  NOTIFICATION: 'message'

                }//end data
            }//end payload

            const options = {
              content_available: true
            }

//send message
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationTokens, payload, options).then( response => {
```

Comment: And you see that you have used `content_available: true` and not `'content-available' : 1` that could not work in any way. I know that for sure because I also use silent notification. As for the fact that you use FCF I got it now.

Comment: agreed, although the other key point is that it needed to be part of `options` and not `notification`.