# Blank verification page stil opening after Silent Notifications be configured

Tags: react-native, push-notification, firebase-authentication, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

I've configured Xcode and Firebase Console with silent notifications. I'm receiving the push notifications and the response from the firebase after try to signing, but in middle of the process, firebase is opening a blank page to verify If I'm not a robot.

PS: Before the silent notifications configuration be done, this blank page was opening and after that, a recaptcha appears.

PS2: AFTER silent notifications configuration, only the blank page appears.

someone?

Tks.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43119052/1531971

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that only in simulators should open blank verification pages with recaptcha or not... but not on devices, so I enabled some background options on Xcode and looks it solved so far.